# Python: How to compare text in user input with content in text file or mysql database?

Tags: python

If I add these 2 variables in my python app, how do I compare input entered into 'key' with line of texts (integer e.g: 12345, 67890) for finding matching value in a text file located at www.example.com/key.txt ?

```
name = raw_input("What is your name ? ")
key = raw_input("What is your key ? ")
```

I've also thought about comparing it with database content, but below code don't work.

```
import mysql.connector

email = raw_input("What is your email ? ")
key = raw_input("What is your key ? ")

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password="79032", database='license_key')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT email_address, license_key FROM validation "
         "WHERE license_key LIKE key")

cursor.execute(query, (license_key))

for (email_address, license_key) in cursor:
  print("you license key is valid"))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: The first part would be to read the file in to some data structure. Have you made an attempt to read your files? What specific issues are you facing?

Comment: like reading from a database table and compare ?

Comment: Well that's along the lines of what you're describing. You could make a dictionary of your `key.txt` lines. What I'm suggesting is that your question doesn't appear to show that you've tried anything to solve your issue; there are plenty of resources already for this kind of thing. I'm interested in what you tried from those resources and what difficulties remain.

Comment: @roganjosh I've update the question, could you show me how to compare it database content ? I'm thinking about simpler way to validate license key for an app.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to read in the text file (a dictionary would work), then check for the key / assign a new value that way. You could then save it to text again, if desired.

Example: If you had a text file with two columns (1st being the key and 2nd the value), you could do the following:

```
example_dict = {}
# Open the file (this takes a path to the file)
with open("key.txt") as f:
    # Loop over each line
    for line in f:
       # Split each line and get the 1st (key) and 2nd (val) values
       (key, val) = line.split()
       # Cast the key to an integer (not necessary if your key is a string)
       example_dict[int(key)] = val
```

Then, look for the key:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name ? ")
key = raw_input("What is your key ? ")

# Here you check if the key is present
if key in example_dict:
   # Here you set it to something new, like the name you got, if you wanted to
   example_dict[key] = name
```